# reinstall previous version on dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, downgrade

So, I tried to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 on a dual boot system but Ubuntu will not load. I then tried to boot from a USB stick with "start-up disc creator" and a 12.04 iso image(BIOS set to boot from USB first) but computer just goes to GRUB menu. I actually dislike Unity soooo much that I would like to just put 10.10 back in anyway (started with this and have a good CD of it). My dislike of Unity is because the Unity Launcher is driving me crazy! Anytime I get near the "back" button in Firefox that damn launcher pops up! It's like a mosquito in a tent! I've got a 6.3G NTFS and 108G NTFS partion and then a 20G EXT4 partion where I believe the Ubuntu operating system lives. There is also a 346G EXT4 (I believe this is /home) and a 20G swap partition. If I boot from the 10.10 CD, I can install from it? But do I format the 20G partition or what? What about the GRUB2 loader? I don't know why I even tried to upgrade other than the other upgrades worked.I liked 10.10 better and all I want is internet,music and photos.I did manage to back up my files to another USB stick. Help.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Have you checked the ISO for errors ?  if not check it by using this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

2.Make sure about boot priority one more time .

1. 12.04 have gnome-classic too which you can choose from the session button of your login screen , it will be at the username input box .
2. 20GB SWAP means its huge , really HUGE . swap= 2xRAM. please follow .